# Passing a JSON object to ECS instance in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have a containerized app that I want to run on ECS and it requires a configuration file, a JSON object. I defined my ECS instance like the one below in the CloudFormation template.

```json
"ECRInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties": {
                "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
                "Cpu": 256,
                "Memory": 512,
                "ExecutionRoleArn": {
                    "Ref": "ECSTaskRole"
                },
                "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "my_app",
                        "Image": "...",
                        "PortMappings": [
                            {"ContainerPort": 8080}
                        ],
                        "LogConfiguration": {
                            "LogDriver": "awslogs",
                            "Options": {
                                "awslogs-group": {
                                    "Ref": "CloudWatchLogsGroup"
                                },
                                "awslogs-region": {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my_app"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Is there a way that I can pass my configuration file to the ECS instance through the CloudFormation template and possibly add a section to my code to receive that configuration object? Something like the below:

```js
// readCfg() reads the configuration object given in the CloudFormation template.
const configuration = readCfg();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not sensitive data, just pass it as a string in an [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-environment). It's exposed to NodeJS in `process.env.MY_VAR_NAME`, all other languages can read environment too.

If it's sensitive data (passwords, access tokens and such like), [create a secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html) in SecretsManager and populate this secret outside your template (so that it's not getting exposed in your template code).

Then, inside your container's code, read the secret:

```ts
import { SecretsManagerClient, GetSecretValueCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";
await new SecretsManagerClient().send(new GetSecretValueCommand({SecretId: "my_secret_id"}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pass a JSON string with a length of 50k+ as an environment variable.